# Unable to include connection.php file to reuse the connection to database

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, require

I'm having some problem to include a connection file to my php page.

I have this connessione.php which receive from login.php the user and password to connect to my db:

```
<?php   
    $host="localhost";
    $user=$_POST["username"];
    $password= $_POST["password"];
    $database = "Park";
    $lingua=$_POST["lingua"];
    $myconn= new mysqli($host,$user,$password,$database); 

    if($myconn->connect_error){
        Header('Location: login.html');
    }else{
        Header('Location: form.html');
    }
?>
```

This is my form.php that should use the connection.

```
<?php
    require ('connessione.php');
    $query="SELECT CodicePin from Pin";
    $res=$myconn->query($query);
    $row=$res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
    print_r($row);
?>
```

The problem is that it is unable to use $myconn established in connessione.php and when I try to login with right user/psw i'll be redirect to login.php.

However if i try to modify connessione.php like this and it execute the query without problem.

```
<?php   
        $host="localhost";
        $user=$_POST["username"];
        $password= $_POST["password"];
        $database = "Park";
        $lingua=$_POST["lingua"];
        $myconn= new mysqli($host,$user,$password,$database); 

        if($myconn->connect_error){
            Header('Location: login.html');
        }else{
        $query="SELECT CodicePin from Pin";
        $res=$myconn->query($query);
        $row=$res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
        print_r($row);
        }
    ?>
```

How i can use the same connection established by connessione.php in other php page?
Thanks, and sorry about my english :)

Comment: Your title *"Unable to include connection.php file"* contradicts itself with the file name you used after.

Comment: DB connection using POST variables? Strange... POST variables are available just in a page after the form is sent.

Comment: your connection only gets processed when the POST arrays are filled, that's why it's not working. Why you want to do that, is beyond me.

Comment: u must have static connection configuration to use in all files
POST wont work there.

Comment: You have to use sessions / cookies so your server can remember the clients when they make additional requests.

Comment: I'm trying to create a small web server on my raspberry to insert some data in a database.
I did a simple form in login.html where i get credentials to access into database so i tought to pass them with post to connessione.php.
I understood what's it's wrong, connessione.php execute the post every time it is used.
Now how I can get the username and password only one time and reuse the connection in other pages?
Sorry but I never did that before.

Comment: Check the answer below

Comment: You speak about `form.php` and `form.html`. Do you have two files or it's just a typo? The same question about `login.php` and `login.html`! Please provide the exact file names for each of the codes in the question. And please explain exactly the workflow you want to have. Your codes are not (anymore) important for us in your case, because you made them wrong and we have to give you another solution, the right one. For that we need the workflow from you. And include the file names in your description as well. Ok?

Answer (score 0):

In Connection Page, i named DbConfig.php

```
 // DB connection
    $host="localhost"; // Host name
    $username="root"; // Mysql username
    $password=""; // Mysql password
    $db_name="demoproject"; // Database name

    // Connect to server and select databse.
    $con=mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password","$db_name") or die("cannot connect");
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to Connect Database: ". mysqli_connect_error();
//You can redirect here
    exit();
}
```

in Process Page

```
require_once("DbConfig.php");

$sql="SELECT CodicePin from Pin";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
var_dump($row);
```

Comment: what Explanation do u need after I have given you a demo of code.?

Comment: Why his code was not working and what did you do to make it work and why did you do it that way.

Comment: PHP is open source anybody can write at their own way . @hungrykoala

Answer (score -1):

You have to store your login post (session would be the best match for),
then use the $_SESSION on mysqli connection;

remember to start your session before use it

POSTs are sent only when you send your login form, so if you navigate you loss your first post